# How do I access list items metadata, but maintain the list?

Tags: msbuild

I have created a custom .targets file with following item group

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="Foo" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I can access that collection or list with `@(Foo)` and I get `'Item1.txt;Item2.txt'`

If I do `%(Foo.FullPath)` I get `'C:\projectfolder\Item1.txt'`

How do I use both the meta data tag %, and the "collection" tag @ together to get
`'C:\projectfolder\Item1.txt;C:\projectfolder\subfolder\Item2.txt'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@(Foo->'%(Foo.FullPath)')
```

You can read more [MSBuild Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Just for reference, MSBuild says you can just use @(foo->'%(FullPath)') because the item is inferred